# Getting access to a dynamic table from dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, temp-tables, sp-executesql

Good day StackOverflow

The table that I create from my dynamic sql can have any number of columns as it is a pivot table.

```
-- Pivot the table so we get the UW as columns rather than rows
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = '
SELECT *
FROM #PreProcessed
PIVOT (SUM(Quotes)
        FOR [UW] IN (' + @UWColumns + ')
        ) AS bob'
```

I run this code to run my dynamic sql.

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
                  N'@UWColumns nvarchar(MAX)',
                  @UWColumns
```

My question is, how do I store the resulting table? Especially when I don't know how many columns it will have or even what the columns will be called?

I tried the code below but it doesn't work

```
   INSERT INTO #Temp
   EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
                  N'@UWColumns nvarchar(MAX)',
                  @UWColumns
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: You'll probably need to create a real table.  A temp table created outside of `sp_exectutesql` will have scope within in.  But anything transient (temp tables, variables, etc) created within it will de-allocate when the scope returns to the calling code.  So, dynamic SQL to create a table, as well as dynamic SQL to populate it.  Or, re-factor your code to work with the source (normalised) data.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses `SELECT * INTO ....`, as opposed to the `CREATE TABLE AS` syntax.  So you'll need to modify your dynamic sql to:

```
 SELECT * INTO <YOUR TABLE>
    FROM #PreProcessed
    PIVOT (SUM(Quotes)
            FOR [UW] IN (' + @UWColumns + ')
            ) AS bob'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but I get this error:
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 35
Invalid object name '#temp'.

Comment: Oh, didn't catch the table variable in there. I'm not sure how you would do that, since you have to declare the variable.  Why are you trying to save the results in a temp table?

Comment: I am writing quite a complex report and I need to add some more information to the data I am producing. Unfortunately this all will be wrapped into a sp that needs to be run when ever. My colleague suggested using a second table and joining on my date column

Comment: So you need it only for the life of your stored procedure?  Maybe you could use it as a CTE? `;with <select statement> as <CTE NAME>`

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find around this problem was to do **all** of my calculations in the dynamic sql. Which meant I had to work on two tables.

```
-- Pivot the table so we get the UW as columns rather than rows
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = '
SELECT * INTO #temp
FROM #PreProcessed
PIVOT (SUM(Quotes)
        FOR [UW] IN (' + @UWColumns + ')
        ) AS bob

SELECT DISTINCT t1.Date, d.Declines AS ''Declines'' , '+@UWColumns+'
FROM #temp AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
#Declines AS d ON t1.DATE = d.DATE
'

PRINT @SQL

EXEC(@SQL)
```